# Java decimals using %.2f

Tags: java

I'm new to java and I'm writing a code for a monthly payment calculator, the only problem that I'm having is rounding errors that I'm getting. I need to calculate the monthly payments which I did by:

```
System.out.printf("Your monthly payment will be:$%.2f", payment);
```

this part is coming out ok

Now I have to figure out how much they will pay at the end of their payments so I did :

```
System.out.printf("You will be paying a total amount of $%.2f", payment * months);
```

This is where my problem lies, in the first print out it's rounding the payment, in the second print out its rounding the payment times the months, I need it to round ONLY the payment and then multiply that by the months but I can't figure out how. Any help would be great.

Comment: I tried that and it rounds it to a whole number EX: 45.21  =  45.00

Comment: If you're deep into this check out http://javamoney.github.io/ although it may be overkill ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat();
df.setMaximumFractionDigits(2);
double payment_rounded =Double.parseDouble( df.format(payment));
```

Now you have the variable `payment_rounded` as a double with 2 places of decimal. And you can use this variable in both cases.

Answer (score 1):

Use `BigDecimal` instead of `double`. The notation is uglier. Use `new BigDecimal("12.34")` to let BigDecimal know the precision. The usage is much uglier as you need methods like `add` and `multiply`.

BTW in the database use DECIMALS too, to have a fixed precision, and not a floating point approximation.

For a reason, do a search.

Comment: What a shame you didn't actually GIVE the reason here.  You would have earnt my upvote if you had.

Comment: @DavidWallace thanks, next time (which will certainly come) I will find a more elaborate answer, or elaborate myself.

Answer (score 0):

```
System.out.printf("You will be paying a total amount of $%.2f", (Math.round((payment * 100.0)) / 100.0) * months);
```

This should round to 2 decimal places.  What it does is move the decimal place over 2 spots then round then move back 2 spots.  If you don't want to use BigDecimal this will work if you still want to use primitive type double.

Comment: An easier way to get a `double` is to just divide by `100.0`: `Math.round(payment * 100) / 100.0`.